# Deploy Custom App Page WSP 2010 in 2019

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2010

Good morning,

We are in the process to upgrade our 2010 environment to 2019 and we are trying to do an inventory of which solutions don't need to be touched to optimize before the upgrade process. For example: I have a solution with a custom page for a list where we replaced the new, display and edit forms using SharePoint the

```
Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
```

But when I load the custom page in 2019, none of the controls that uses the Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls are not loaded. Did this happen with some too? Do I need to make any modification in the web.config?